# Java multithreading : Why Synchronised block does not work in call cases

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

I came across the following statement while reading The complete Reference book of java.

**The synchronized Statement**

> While creating synchronized methods within classes that you create is
> an easy and effective means of achieving synchronization, **it will not
> work in all cases.**

However I did not understand the last part where it says "It will not work in all cases". What can be good example where synchronize method will work but not block?

Comment: I think you took this out of context, there should be more text that further explains that. `synchronized` always works in and by itself, does as expected. But if you do not know what the calls inside the `synchronized` block do, it they are thread-safe, then `synchronized` alone might not help you there.

Comment: As an example to the above comment: What if your synchronized method simply edits an object, however, that object could be accessible to other threads. In that case using `synchronized` won't block any of the other threads from editing the object, it will only block them from calling the same method, so your method would not be thread safe even if you had a `synchronized` method.

Comment: Right, we could use an example of what "will not work."  There's just to many mistakes possible to call them all out.  What are you referring to?